# Displaying Multiple RecyclerView with same type Adapters

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to display 3 RecyclerViews in the same Fragment, with each RecyclerView displaying different types of matches (Finished matches, This week matches and Not yet matches).

I have instantiated 3 RVs and 3 Adapters as seen in the code below:

```
matchesList_rv_finished = view.findViewById(R.id.finished_upcoming_matches_rv);
    matchesList_rv_finished.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    matchesList_rv_finished.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);

    matchesList_rv_Week = view.findViewById(R.id.Week_upcoming_matches_rv);
    matchesList_rv_Week.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    matchesList_rv_Week.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);

    matchesList_rv_NotYet = view.findViewById(R.id.NotYet_upcoming_matches_rv);
    matchesList_rv_NotYet.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager3 = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    matchesList_rv_NotYet.setLayoutManager(layoutManager3);

    matchAdapter1 = new MatchAdapter();
    matchAdapter2 = new MatchAdapter();
    matchAdapter3 = new MatchAdapter();
```

This is how I receive 3 lists of matches and setting the 3 adapters:

```
Model.instance.getUpComingMatches(new Model.MatchListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(ArrayList<Match> finishedMatches,
                               ArrayList<Match> thisWeekMatches,
                               ArrayList<Match> notYetMatches) {
            finishedMatchList = finishedMatches;
            matchAdapter1.setMatchesData(finishedMatchList);
            matchesList_rv_finished.setAdapter(matchAdapter1);
            
            ThisWeekMatchList = thisWeekMatches;
            matchAdapter2.setMatchesData(ThisWeekMatchList);
            matchesList_rv_Week.setAdapter(matchAdapter2);
            
            NotYetMatchList = notYetMatches;
            matchAdapter3.setMatchesData(NotYetMatchList);
            matchesList_rv_NotYet.setAdapter(matchAdapter3);
            
        }
    });
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but it seems like the last adapter is overriding the data of the previous 2 adapters, instead of showing 3 different matches in each RV :

[image: I want it to show 3 different matches]

I think i'm lacking some basic information here or maybe there's just a simpler way to implement this?
Thanks for the help!

EDIT: posting the fragment xml layout: [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/upcoming_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UpcomingMatchesFragment" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/Week_upcoming_matches_rv"
        android:layout_width="382dp"
        android:layout_height="167dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/finished_upcoming_matches_rv"
        android:layout_width="382dp"
        android:layout_height="167dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/NotYet_upcoming_matches_rv" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/NotYet_upcoming_matches_rv"
        android:layout_width="382dp"
        android:layout_height="167dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Week_upcoming_matches_rv" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post also your layout?

Comment: @Jameido if you mean the fragment layout then yes just posted it.

Comment: The xml code is more important in this case

Comment: @Jameido posted

Comment: check if removing `.setHasFixedSize(true);` from your RecyclerViews shows the missing lists?

Answer (score 0):

The technology is already exist on apps such as sport365 and onefootball. I have the same issue